# Jenkins displays "Build Success" even when tests are failed due to error handling in scripts (try and catch block)

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

**Note**: I am unable to paste the exact framework and code as the server I work on is not accessible from outside. Hence, I will try to explain my problem in simple words and examples.

**Overview** - I have created a Selenium automation framework which includes TestNG, Maven (POM.XML), Test data files, Scripts and few reusable functions.

**Issue I am facing** - I use Jenkins to execute my scripts. Jenkins calls POM.XML file which inturn calls testng.xml file (In testng.xml file, I have mentioned the scripts to be executed)

Let's say, I have to perform login action

**Main Script**

```
@Test
Public void maintest ()
{

//I use Extent reports for reporting purpose and hence I have created extent 
 //reporting reusable function which is called in the below fashion.

//If Login method returns pass, ExtentReportingFunc passes Pass to its 
 //function and displays Pass for that particular Login step in the report.

ExtentReportingFunc (Login(UserName, Password));
}
```

**Reusable functions**

```
Public String Login (String UN, String Pass)
{
//Sendkeys and set UN
driver.findelement (By.id("username")).sendkeys(UN);

//Sendkeys and set Password
driver.findelement (By.id("password")).sendkeys(pass);

//Click Login
driver.findelement (By.id("login")).click ();

//Verifying the message "Welcome User" is displayed after login
   try 
   {
      if (driver.findlement (By.id("welcomemessage")).isdisplayed ();
      {
        return pass;
      }
   } catch (Exception e)
   {
     //If welcome message is not found then return fail to the Reporting function
     return "fail";

     //Below code will be unreachable which is correct as per Java but that is the challenge.
      // I tried several ways to find a work around to return fail as above as 
      // well throw exception but no luck till now.
      // Upon throwing exception in the below way, Jenkins displays build as 
      //failed. If it is not done, though the script has failed, 
      //Jenkins displays "BUILD PASSED"

       throw e;
   }
}

//Extent Reporting function
ExtentReportingFunc (String status)
{
log.report (status);
}
```

Here, the challenge is - In the catch block, If I DO NOT mention "throw e", Jenkins won't understand that the failure has occurred and display "BUILD PASSED" in it's console output. I want it to display "BUILD FAILURE" in Jenkins console. Reason why I want it to display "BUILD FAILED" is - I have integrated JIRA with Jenkins. Only when jenkins show BUILD FAILED, it logs automatically bugs to JIRA. If it is "BUILD PASSED" and though finished status is UNSTABLE, no failures will be displayed in the test result section of Jenkins NOR it logs any bugs in JIRA.

However, that time I won't be able to pass return "fail" to the main reporting function so that it can display login step as failure in the report.

I understand, as per JAVA we can either throw or return in the catch block but not both. Is there any other way we can make this work?

I already had created end to end framework but later realised this problem when I started integrating with Jenkins (or else everything was fine till then).

Answer (score 1):

Why Don't you add assert fail inside you catch statement, that way you are forcing testng test to fail when its inside the catch statement

org.testng.Assert.fail("Im failing here due to ... you can add your e message here");

Just add the line of code before

```
return "fail";
```

and keep the rest of the function as is

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I will be writing following in my catch block - **return "Fail";** and **org.testng.Assert.fail("..");**. In this case, will Jenkins show "BUILD FAILURE" in its console?

Comment: I updated the answer, just add the code before the return "fail" so you will fail your testng test and then return the value you want to the html function for your report. Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for your time. Will try this and update you on the result.

Comment: As soon I add assert in the catch block, it is giving lot of import errors (import of other classes that I have made) . Assert is causing trouble.

Comment: You dont have testng in your POM file ? can you share you POM code?

Comment: Challenge is I cannot take it out of the server machine. I have testng in POM under surefire tag.

Comment: OK, there is not much i can do here if i cant see the erros you have. Try to have you login function in the same class where the @Test just to try and see if it works because The reusable function is not inside a testng class and that might be the reason you see all this import issues. Also i dont know why you using extent report like that. If you want a proper way to use it , you can take a look at my simple selenium framework and use if if you want Link is https://github.com/mbn217/SeleniumWithMaven

Comment: Sure. Will check. Btw I fixed that issue by creating a function named "throw new exception.........." And calling it after steps. As of now everything is working perfectly fine. However I will try to convert complete framework to testng slowly.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using asserts, so whenever your condition doesn't met the assert will fail and so will your test case and jenkins will show the status of the build as "UNSTABLE" instead of "PASS".

For example, in the above example, instead of using try catch and if condition in the try, it can be solved by a single line of assert which will also give you your desired build status as well.

You can replace the above code with:
`Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("welcomemessage")).isDisplayed(), "Element is not present on the page");`

So in this, if the element is not displayed on the page, assert will be failed as it is expecting true value but will get false and your jenkins build status will be shown as unstable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, the challenge is - I have to return something back to the Reportingfunction in order for it to display the result in the HTML report. If the login method sends "PASS", it displays PASS and vice versa. In case i use Assert.AssertTrue, it will definitely help in showing build as UNSTABLE but ReportingFunction won't have any value returned from the Loginfunction.

Comment: In addition to the above point, As of now, Jenkins displays build as UNSTABLE. However, the result will be displayed as "BUILD PASSED" instead of "BUILD FAILED" though the overall Jenkins status is "UNSTABLE".

Comment: For jenkins, the build failed means the execution got terminated due to compile time error, browser setup failure etc. And i guess you are using extentReporting which in turns use the listener class, which will get the status of the test class after it failed/passed and you would be getting the status as failed in this case as well. I am also using extent reporting and asserts in my framework. Though, i will be checking other people's answer on this question because as per my knowledge, jenkins doesn't give the build status as FAILED for failed test cases.

Comment: If I run the above piece of code I shared, Once the code reaches catch block and if I have mentioned "throw e" in the catch block, I consistently observed that Jenkins displays "**Build Failed**" with Finished status as UNSTABLE. Note that, in the above example - Code reaches catch block only when it fails to see the message "Welcome User" and hence fails. So a little surprising with the BUILD FAILED message in Jenkins. If I remove "throw e" from the catch block, it displays BUILD PASSED.

Comment: Yes i was taking about the finished status only that it comes as unstable when a test case fails or throws an exception. But in my opinion, when we know the expected result, we shouldn’t be throwing an exception, we should use assertion for those cases. Lets see what other people answer on this, might add to my knowledge as well if there is some other way to do it.

Comment: Another reason why I want it to display "BUILD FAILED" is  - I have integrated JIRA with Jenkins. Only when jenkins show BUILD FAILED, it logs automatically bugs to JIRA. If it is "BUILD PASSED" and though finished status is UNSTABLE, no failures will be displayed in the test result section of Jenkins NOR it logs any bugs in JIRA.

Comment: I have also integrated jira with jenkins but that is to the test case level, as in whenever a test case fails, it makes a jira for the same. But why have you integrated it with the whole build status, because if multiple test cases failed, build status will be only one and as per your code only one jira ticket generated, however ideally it should make one jira for each test case failed.

Comment: I have integrated Jenkins at test case and test step level too. Let's say my first script contains - Login, do some actions, logout... Here, every step like Login, some actions, logout will be monitored separately. Let's say some actions (2nd Step) and Logout (3rd Step) fails - In this case, Jenkins display both the failures (2nd and 3rd step) and will be reported in JIRA.

Comment: But why is jenkins required here? Whenever your test case/step fails you should hit the jira api there only and can generate the jira for it, jenkins shouldn’t come into play for this.

Comment: Jenkins was only used to trigger the automation scripts via POM.XML automatically and to achieve Master-Slave concept for some reason. As it is easy to integrate JIRA there, I did it as an addition.

Comment: Ohh.. in my code i am actually hitting the post api of jira to make a ticket whenever test case fails, so i dont need jenkins dependency in that case. Well lets see if someone else has any other answer to it, but you can use my logics  as well to solve your purpose.

Comment: Sure. Another thing is - Only if Jenkins show "BUILD FAILURE", it will show failures in its report. But if test scripts like login functionality lets say fail, and even though if Jenkins show "BUILD PASSED" (As mostly we handle it cleanly in catch block), it will be difficult for stakeholders or testers to know the reason for it to fail.. As we see Passed:1, Failed:0, Skipped:0 (Though something like login functionality has failed). The moment we do "throw e" from catch block, it shows Passed:0, Failed:1, Skipped:0 along with "BUILD FAILURE". Sure. We will see if someone else has answer.

Comment: Thats what i am saying, you should never handle the test cases with the  catch block as it tempers with your test result, you should use asserts and in that case the build status will be unstable and unstable in itself means some test case has failed and when you open the report you would be able to see which test case has failed. And build failure coming from jenkins shows that something wrong is there with the code like compile time error. Lets see what others have there to answer.

Comment: I fixed that issue by creating a function named "throw new exception.........." And calling it after steps. As of now everything is working perfectly fine. However I will try to convert complete framework to testng using assert fail slowly.

Comment: Ok great !! Please upvote the answer if it helped you :)